# Multiple Implementation of service interface for different API controllers Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-2.1

I have many API controllers that have IService, ILog, and some more constructor parameters.

IService have different implementation:

```
public interface IService
{
   void Process();
}
```

**DefaultService: IService** and **CallService: IService** as an example.

I created two api controllers, **DefaultController** and **CallController**.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly IService _defaultService;
   private readonly ILog _log;

   public DefaultController(IService defaultService, ILog log, .... other parameters)
   {
      _defaultService = defaultService;
      _log = log;
   }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CallController: ControllerBase
{
   private readonly IService _callService;
   private readonly ILog _log;

   public CallController(IService callService, ILog log,.... other parameters)
   {
      _callService = callService;
      _log = log;
   }
}
```

What I want is, to inject **DefaultService to DefaultController** and **CallService to CallController**.

So I tried the following using SO answer, but keeps giving me the default one

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<DefaultService>()
    .As<IService>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<DefaultService>()
    .Named<IService>("ForDefaultController")
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

//updated after comment -----------
builder.RegisterType<DefaultController>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IService>("ForDefaultController"));
// -------------------


builder.RegisterType<CallService>()
    .Named<IService>("ForCallController")
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<CallController>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IService>("ForCallController"));
```

So, what should I do?

If you want the sample project, you can clone [this](https://github.com/ashGHub/Autofac) GitHub repository.

Comment: You will have to do the same for default controller. It wont know which dependency implementation to use without being directly told.

Comment: @Nkosi I did that but, still it is injecting the default service for both controllers

Comment: [Have you read the docs? This is an FAQ.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: @TravisIllig thanks... I went with redesigning my interface. I don't want to use MetadataAttributes, because I will be tied to Autofac. And the other options, won't seem to work.